# Captha image not getting generated in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha

I am using MvcCaptcha.
For this, I used this reference
http://sameercode.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/mvc-captcha-using-dll/

http://captchamvc.codeplex.com/releases/view/103937

[image]

I followed all the steps, but the captcha image is not getting generated.

Please see the attached image

Do i have to add any config settings..

The image that should appear is

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the URL of that image that isn't showing? Using dev tools and inspecting on that broken image.

Comment: I'm the developer of CaptchaMvc project. Ensure that you used MVC4 library and if the issue remained please create work item [here](http://captchamvc.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Comment: Issue resolved... Alongwith CaptchaMVC.dll, i also need to include xml file. I add the reference using Nuget and it worked

Comment: Most likely, you have used the MVC3 library instead of MVC4 and then Nuget added the correct library.

Answer (score 0):

For this example I will use a implementation for MathCaptcha. At the Controller you should add:

```
using CaptchaMvc.Attributes;
...
// At the action that process your form you have to add the [CaptchaVerify] atttribute
[HttpPost]
[CaptchaVerify("Captcha result is not valid.")] // Captcha is now able for validation
public ActionResult yourAction(FormCollection collection)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "The captcha answer is not correct.";
            return View("SameViewForm");
        }
        else
        {
            ...
            // Whatever you have to do when Captcha answer is correct.
            return View();
        }
}
```

At the view:

```
// Add
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    <label style="color: red">@ViewBag.Error</label>
    @Html.MathCaptcha()
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```